# Is it bad form to make new types/datas for clarity?

Tags: haskell, type-safety, type-alias, newtype

I would like to know if it is bad form to do something like this:

```
data Alignment = LeftAl | CenterAl | RightAl
type Delimiter = Char
type Width     = Int

setW :: Width -> Alignment -> Delimiter -> String -> String
```

Rather than something like this:

```
setW :: Int -> Char -> Char -> String -> String
```

I do know that remaking those types effectively does nothing but take up a few lines in exchange for clearer code. However, if I use the type `Delimiter` for multiple functions, this would be much clearer to someone importing this module, or reading the code later.

I am relatively new to Haskell so I do not know what is good practice for this type of stuff. If this is not a good idea, or there is something that would improve clarity that is preferred, what would that be?

Comment: No -- rather, I would consider the former a _good_ form. Your type `Alignment` makes it clear that there are only three valid values, and gives nice names to those. By comparison `Char` is much more vague, and allows invalid values. Aliases like `Delimiter` and `Width` are less useful, but nice to have, especially if there are many functions using them.

Comment: A delimeter is what you use to measure meat at the supermarket. A delimiter is a boundary between segments of something.

Comment: Another possible solution to make the code clearer would be to use as argument a record with named fields (this isn't mutually exclusive with the use of newtypes). The decision to use a record depends on how closely related the arguments are, if we don't mind losing partial application, if we want to provide a "default" record argument, and so on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're using type aliases, they only slightly help with code readability. However, it's better to use `newtype` instead of `type` for better type-safety. Like this:

```
data Alignment = LeftAl | CenterAl | RightAl
newtype Delimiter = Delimiter { unDelimiter :: Char }
newtype Width     = Width { unWidth :: Int }

setW :: Width -> Alignment -> Delimiter -> String -> String
```

You will deal with extra wrapping and unwrapping of `newtype`. But the code will be more robust against further refactorings. [This style guide](https://kowainik.github.io/posts/2019-02-06-style-guide#data-types) suggests to use `type` only for specializing polymorphic types.

Comment: Worth pointing out that calls to `unDelimiter` and `unWidth` are "zero-cost", in that they are only necessary for type checking; there is no actual call at run-time.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning when a type alias *is* worth using, which I think is for giving a shorter name to something like a monad stack (`type App = ReaderT SomeEnvironment IO ()`, e.g.).

Comment: I'm no expert in lenses but I'm pretty sure the `Lens` library uses type aliases as well

Comment: `pipes` is another example: there's one basic data type, `data Proxy a' a b' b m r`, and everything thing else is just an alias that hides the use of concrete types as arguments to `Proxy`. (E.g., `type Producer b = Proxy X () () b`.) (On the other hand, `pipes` also defines `type X = Void` for reasons that aren't really clear.)

Comment: Adding that for `Width`, you can add `deriving(Num)` to allow to still do arithmetic on it without any clunky boxing and unboxing

Comment: @chepner `X` exists, at least in part, for historical reasons. Years ago, `Data.Void` wasn't in *base*, so depending on the *void* package was necessary for using `Void`. At some point. *pipes* elminated the dependency by rolling its own. When `Data.Void` made it into base, `X` became a synonym.

Comment: Note that Delimeter is a spelling error.  It should be Delim**i**ter. This is going to cause someone some serious head banging debugging it.

Comment: Type synonyms are all over `lens`, which uses them to do certain sorts of magic that newtypes would interfere with (though I wonder if `QuantifiedConstraints` can work around that now). They're also more generally useful with higher-rank types. Type synonyms also show up in heavily typish code as degenerate type families. `type Reverse xs = ReverseOnto '[] xs; type family ReverseOnto acc xs where ...`. And with `ConstraintKinds`, constraint synonyms are especially useful as one-offs to declare a class and its sole instance when there are many constraints.

Comment: That said, my general view is that beginners shouldn't use type synonyms.

Comment: @chepner, for a monad transformer stack, it's usually best to declare a newtype, enable `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to get the instances you need, and define functions with more domain-appropriate names. For example, just because you're using `ReaderT Blob` doesn't mean you need `MonadReader Blob`. Just define `getBlob = T ask`.

Answer (score 14):

I wouldn't consider that bad form, but clearly, I don't speak for the Haskell community at large. The language feature exists, as far as I can tell, for that particular purpose: to make the code easier to read.

One can find examples of the use of type aliases in various 'core' libraries. For example, the `Read` class defines this method:

```
readList :: ReadS [a]
```

The `ReadS` type is just a type alias

```
type ReadS a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

Another example is the [`Forest` type in `Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Tree.html#t:Forest):

```
type Forest a = [Tree a]
```

As *Shersh* points out, you can also wrap new types in `newtype` declarations. That's often useful if you need to somehow constrain the original type in some way (e.g. with [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors)) or if you want to add functionality to a type without creating orphan instances (a typical example is to define QuickCheck `Arbitrary` instances to types that don't otherwise come with such an instance).

Comment: I second your opinion. Even though `type`defs don't give any extra typechecker guarantees that a `newtype` would, they _are_ a useful means of quickly sorting out your signatures. This is especially useful in the prototyping stage – quickly get together the types you need (as well as some you may in the end _not really_ need) without having to write any boilerplate code. But because it's already a distinguishable _name_, you can easily change the definition to a proper `newtype` later on an the compiler will make it easy to adapt the code.

Comment: We have, I believe, removed `Forest` from the type signatures for all exported functions. Why? It's confusing! You'd expect `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Forest a -> Forest b`, but that's not the case! Rather,  `fmap :: (Tree a -> Tree b) -> Forest a -> Forest b`. Just terrible. `ReadS` is awful for the same reason: people expect parsers to have `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` instances that behave in certain ways, and `ReadS` looks like a parser type, but its instances are all `(->) String`. Terribly confusing!

Comment: Er.... Actually not... I thought we had... I meant to ... I must not have merged something.....

Answer (score 10):

Using `newtype`—which creates a new type with the same representation as the underlying type but not substitutable with it— is considered *good* form. It's a cheap way to avoid [primitive obsession](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession/), and it's especially useful for Haskell because in Haskell the names of function arguments are not visible in the signature.

Newtypes can also be a place on which to hang useful typeclass instances.

Given that newtypes are ubiquitous in Haskell, over time the language has gained some tools and idioms to manipulate them:

- [Coercible](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) A "magical" typeclass that simplifies conversions between newtypes and their underlying types, when the newtype constructor is in scope. Often useful to avoid boilerplate in function implementations.

  `ghci> coerce (Sum (5::Int)) :: Int`

  `ghci> coerce [Sum (5::Int)] :: [Int]`

  `ghci> coerce ((+) :: Int -> Int -> Int) :: Identity Int -> Identity Int -> Identity Int`
- [`ala`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils-0.0.0/docs/CoercibleUtils.html#v:ala). An idiom (implemented in various packages) that simplifies the selection of a newtype that we might want to use with functions like `foldMap`.

  `ala Sum foldMap [1,2,3,4 :: Int] :: Int`
- [`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving). An extension for auto-deriving instances for your newtype based on instances available in the underlying type.
- [`DerivingVia`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DerivingVia) A more general extension, for auto-deriving instances for your newtype based on instances available in *some other* newtype with the same underlying type.

Comment: Using `coerce` directly is crude since inference requires guidance in the extreme, but very powerful. Ideally you never have to use it directly but we're not there yet. Great answer!

Answer (score 6):

One important thing to note is that `Alignment` versus `Char` is not just a matter of clarity, but one of correctness. Your `Alignment` type expresses the fact that there are only three valid alignments, as opposed to however many inhabitants `Char` has. By using it, you avoid trouble with invalid values and operations, and also enable GHC to informatively tell you about incomplete pattern matches if warnings are turned on.

As for the synonyms, opinions vary. Personally, I feel `type` synonyms for small types like `Int` can increase cognitive load, by making you track different names for what is rigorously the same thing. That said, [leftaroundabout makes a great point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062048/is-it-bad-form-to-make-new-types-datas-for-clarity#comment100652729_57062465) in that this kind of synonym can be useful in the early stages of prototyping a solution, when you don't necessarily want to worry about the details of the concrete representation you are going to adopt for your domain objects.

(It is worth mentioning that the remarks here about `type` largely don't apply to `newtype`. The use cases are different, though: while `type` merely introduces a different name for the same thing, `newtype` introduces a different thing by fiat. That can be a surprisingly powerful move -- see [danidiaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57063008/2751851) for further discussion.)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely is good, and here is another example, supose you have this data type with some op:

```
data Form = Square Int | Rectangle Int Int | EqTriangle Int

perimeter :: Form -> Int
perimeter (Square s)      = s * 4
perimeter (Rectangle b h) = (b * h) * 2
perimeter (EqTriangle s)  = s * 3

area :: Form -> Int
area (Square s)      = s ^ 2
area (Rectangle b h) = (b * h)
area (EqTriangle s)  = (s ^ 2) `div` 2
```

Now imagine you add the circle:

```
data Form = Square Int | Rectangle Int Int | EqTriangle Int | Cicle Int
```

add its operations:

```
perimeter (Cicle r )      = pi * 2 * r

area (Cicle r)       = pi * r ^ 2
```

it is not very good right? Now I want to use Float... I have to change every Int for Float

```
data Form = Square Double | Rectangle Double Double | EqTriangle Double | Cicle Double


area :: Form -> Double

perimeter :: Form -> Double
```

but, what if, for clarity and even for reuse, I use type?

```
data Form = Square Side | Rectangle Side Side | EqTriangle Side | Cicle Radius

type Distance = Int
type Side = Distance
type Radius = Distance
type Area = Distance

perimeter :: Form -> Distance
perimeter (Square s)      = s * 4
perimeter (Rectangle b h) = (b * h) * 2
perimeter (EqTriangle s)  = s * 3
perimeter (Cicle r )      = pi * 2 * r

area :: Form -> Area
area (Square s)      = s * s
area (Rectangle b h) = (b * h)
area (EqTriangle s)  = (s * 2) / 2
area (Cicle r)       = pi * r * r
```

That allows me to change the type only changing one line in the code, supose I want the Distance to be in Int, I will only change that

```
perimeter :: Form -> Distance
...

totalDistance :: [Form] -> Distance
totalDistance = foldr (\x rs -> perimeter x + rs) 0
```

I want the Distance to be in Float, so I just change:

```
type Distance = Float
```

If I want to change it to Int, I have to make some adjustments in the functions, but thats other issue.

Comment: Good example. Though **1.** I'd argue that `Distance` should never have been `Int` in the first place, [nor `Float` for that matter](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Floating_point), but `Double` – but the point is, which you're making very well here, that _a typedef makes it easy to change this implementation detail_. **2.** It _would_ actually make sense to make a stronger type distinction here, i.e. with `newtype`s rather than `type`defs. Note that `Distance` is not really a number type: multiplying two distances gives an `Area`, and adding a distance to an area doesn't make sense.